# Best container for <Key, <pairOfType1,pairOfType2>>

Tags: java, containers

I'm wondering what the best java like container would it be for

```
<Key, <pairOfType1,pairOfType2>>
```

I have an object1 that is the key and a t1 and  t2.

My classes have the fallowing attributes:

```
public class Patient implements Externalizable {
    protected int iD;
    protected String name;
    protected String CNP;
    protected int   age;


public class Treatment implements Externalizable {
    protected int iD;
    protected String description;

public class Diagnosis implements Externalizable {
        protected int iD;
        protected String name;
        protected String description;
        protected String date;
```

PS: I curious for a 'real program' since my requirements are  to wasve.
I have considered the idea of 
`private Map<Patient, <Diagnosis, Treatmet>> map = new Map<>();`

Comment: Make patient ID the key for your Map. You will need to change it from int to Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just put your Diagnosis and Treatment in a class and pass

```
    Pair<Diagnosis,Treatment> pair = new Pair<>(d,t);
    Map<Key, Pair> map = new Map<>();
    ...
```

where

```
    class Pair<D,T> {
        public D myD;
        public T myT;
        public Pair(D d, T t) {
            myD = d;
            myT = t;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a `Map<Patient, Pair<Diagnosis, Treatment>>` ?

The pair class could look like:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {

    private final T t;
    private final U u;

    public Pair(T t, U u) {
        this.t = t;
        this.u = u;
    }
    //getters
}
```

Comment: For such a simple immutable container, I would even spare the getters and make the fields public (I know that violates Information Hiding, but there is not much to hide in such a simple class)

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary` or a `Map` supports this `Key,Value` lookup.

In your object model you wouldn't have a `t1` and a `t2`, you instead would have a class like this:

```
public class ExternalizableContainer  
{  

    private Externalizable t1;  
    private Externalizable t2;

    public ExternalizableContainer(Externalizable t1,Externalizable t2)  
    {  
           this.t1=t1;
           this.t2=t2;

    }   

}
```

Comment: @assylias see my update.  OP has a misunderstanding about what a `Value` can be.  It also seems you have that same misunderstanding

Comment: I perfectly understand what a Value can be but the op does not and your original answer did not really clarify that.

Comment: @assylias ah yes understandable, the pain of the ninja edit :(

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate object that contains your two values.

```
class MyObject {
  String val1;
  String val2;
  ...
}
```

and then create a map with MyObject as the value. This assumes that the two values you want to store are Strings. @assylias gives a more generic approach by typing the class

```
 new HashMap<Key, MyObject>();
```